# How can I find the number of applicants per tenure-track position in Canada?

Tags: job, tenure-track, canada

There are some anecdotal accounts of number of applicants per tenure-track position in the U.S., but I haven't been able to find anything for Canada. Kinds of information that would be helpful: government statistics, anecdotal accounts from applicants or search committees, estimates by organizations or authors, research studies, formal or informal communications, etc. I need this for the literature review in a paper on a study on working conditions of adjunct instructors in Canada. Thank you for any tips.

Comment: Why not _formal_ communications? Have you tried reading e.g. https://elifesciences.org/articles/54097 and the references given in it?

Comment: Thanks. I added "formal" communications to my post. Thank you for the link. I checked about 25 of the works on that reference list. None of them pertained to Canada. None of the others appeared to contain application metrics.

Comment: I don’t this there’s a database for this except at the university level.  Education is a provincial jurisdiction so certainly not at the federal level (except possibly for CRCs) and provinces rarely meddle with hiring practices of universities except for the occasional random audit: I doubt there’s systematic province-wide statistics.

Comment: Having been on both side of hiring committees, this information generally never leaves the committee itself. I doubt there are statistics on this. I don’t think I could even find it out for my own département outside of committee of which I am a member of.

Comment: @BlaB In France, there are official statistics about this. For instance, at http://cache.media.education.gouv.fr/file/statistiques/37/8/Bilan_provisoire_Recrutement_2021_1419378.pdf (and you can find more statistics at https://www.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/cid118435/personnels-enseignants-du-superieur-bilans-et-statistiques.html ), they say the ratio is about "6,7candidats par poste" (6.7 applicant per position). It would not surprise me that Canada has the same, hidden somewhere.